# Managing ASP.NET Membership of another application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-membership

I have an architectural dilemma..

I need to be managing an existing ASP.NET Web Forms application's users from a different ASP.NET Web Forms application. Both apps have their own databases and implementations of Membership.

I've toyed with the idea of doing it remotely via a web service with CORS. But is there any way I could do it from within the same VS Solution? Ie. add another project to it (for the sole purpose of managing the other app's users). Is there a way to add features of Membership to a Class Library project maybe? Specifically I'm only after the basic CRUD features.

Comment: What is the problem to have 3 projects in one solution? Especially to test webservices this is a normal way.

Comment: "... web service with CORS" - CORS seems orthogonal to the question of managing Membership, but a web service is reasonable; "... same VS solution" - a VS solution can have as many projects as you want, within reason; "...add features of Membership to a Class Library" - yes, just reference the required assembly, and add the appropriate configuration to the application that hosts your class library.

Comment: @Joe, I managed to reference the required assemblies for Membership in a separate Class Library. However the target database is still the one that the original web app in the solution uses. Even when I add the relevant Membership-related sections to the App.config and configure them to point to a different connection string etc., it still uses the original database.

Comment: @user982119 - from what you say, it seems you have added an App.config to a class library project.  That won't be used at runtime: it will use the App.config of the hosting client app (console. WInforms, Wpf or other) or the web.config of the hosting web app.  If you want web app A to manage the Membership database of web app B, you will need to either (a) expose a web service from web app B that can be called by web app A, or, (b) Add two membership providers to web app A, one for the web app A database and a second one for the web app B database.

Comment: @Joe, (Thanks for the reply, much appreciated). Yeah I'm just looking now at adding multiple providers and how to specify (programmatically) which one to use when.

Comment: @user982119 - typically you will have one configured as the default provider, which you will use for authenticating clients.  The others you can reference by name, and provided they are configured correctly, use them for CRUD operations on a different membership database.

Answer (score 1):

Whether they are in the same solution or not doesn't seem to have much to do with managing them from separate web apps.   Integrating at the DB  will restrict the webapps.

A webservice is ideal.  I'd suggest the webservice is agnostic of the fact it's using membership provider underneath.  As your web apps progress you may want to switch out the authentication system with another  ( Like moving to .NET Core ). So the more dependencies you have between both apps means they both have to change together.   Isolating via webservices means they can independently progress.

Comment: AppA would call webservice of AppB and never touch `System.Web.Security.Membership`

Comment: Deleted my comment as you replied. Yeah, thanks, will try again with the web service idea.